# How to check "page viewer" to show specific code

Tags: php, facebook, seo

i make a "pure javascript" web (using HTML5 History API, like Grooveshark or similars), all works ok, but the problem its SEO, especific Facebook & google spiders/tracks.

My idea its to track the "browser" using the PHP vars $_SERVER, and is the "browser" is a specific string, show a diferent HTML (not only the home with the non-executed javascript, AKA no content).

But i have some problems, first, i dont know the "string" of Facebook, Google and another trackers.

Any idea for solve this? (make clasic HTML website not allowed :P)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the `User-Agent` string, and identify the crawlers. [Here](http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/bots) is a full list of values. Just an example: facebook bot uses the `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`

Comment: Sure, i use this, but lot of work.. lot of crawlers.. i think the best method is regexp with "google", "facebook", "bing", etc..

Comment: yes the user-agent often contains the name of the organization.